# Render simple html text such as below to view inside a UIkit based TVOS app

Tags: tvos, tvml, tvjs

How can I render simple html text such as below to view inside a UIkit based  TVOS app?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Since we are not able to use webviews inside a TVOS app,  is there an alternate solution?

To give a little bit of a background , I am building a TVOS, and pulling some static text from a pre-seeded core data storage. It also loads some images referenced by this text from the main bundle.

Answer (score 0):

If the HTML is really that simple, and you can get it into an NSData object, then you can turn it into an attributed string this way:

```
NSData *htmlAsData = (whatever you need to do to populate it)
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *attributes;
NSAttributedString *htmlAsAttributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
    initWithData:htmlAsData
    options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType}
    documentAttributes:&attributes error:&error];
```

And then you can display the `htmlAsAttributedString` just like any other, such as by assigning it to the attributedText property of a UITextView.

If the HTML is even slightly more complicated than that, you probably won't get tolerable results, and you're not going to get any behavior out of it (like being able to follow links).  But it should render.